# Rails carrierwave - can't mass-assign protected attributes error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to build a sample application where users can upload two different types of images to a model named Article. One type of images are images used in the content of the article, and the other is used as a thumbnail. Both types of images are handled by separate polymorphic models named ArticleImage and ArticleThumb.

The problem is, whenever I try to upload a thumbnail, it gives me the "**can't mass-protect protected attributes: :article_thumb**" error. This error *does not* occur for the other type of image uploads.

**Article**

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :title, :article_images_attributes, 
                  :article_thumbs_attributes

  has_many :comments, as: :commentable
  has_many :article_images, as: :attachable, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :article_thumbs, as: :attachable, dependent: :destroy

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :article_images, 
                                reject_if: :all_blank,
                                allow_destroy: true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :article_thumbs, allow_destroy: true

  belongs_to :user

  validates :title, presence: true, length: {maximum: 60}
  validates :user_id, presence: true
  validates :article_images, presence: true
end
```

**ArticleImage**

```
class ArticleImage < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :attachable, polymorphic: true
  attr_accessible :article_image

  mount_uploader :article_image, ArticleImageUploader
end
```

**ArticleThumb**

```
class ArticleThumb < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :attachable, polymorphic: true
  attr_accessible :article_thumb

  mount_uploader :article_thumb, ArticleThumbUploader
end
```

**new.html.erb**

```
<%= simple_nested_form_for @article, html: {multipart: true}, 
    defaults: {required: false} do |f| %>

  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: @article %>

  <%= f.input :title %>

  <div class = "control-label">
    Image file upload
  </div>
  <%= f.simple_fields_for :article_images do |p| %>
    <%= p.file_field :article_image %>
    <%= p.link_to_remove 'Remove' %>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.link_to_add 'Add image', :article_images %>
  <span class="hint_end">Acceptable file formats: JPG, JPEG, GIF, PNG</span>

  <div class = "control-label">
    Thumbnail upload
  </div>
  <%= f.file_field :article_thumb %>
  <span class="hint">
    Automatically resized to 90x90 px.
  </span>
  <span class="hint">
    Default thumbnail is used if no thumbnail gets uploaded.
  </span>
  <span class="hint_end">
    Acceptable file formats: JPG, JPEG, GIF, PNG
  </span>

  <%= f.submit "Upload article" %>
<% end %>
```

I have a feeling this error only requires a very simple fix, but I just can't seem to figure it out. Any help would be appreciated.

As a side note, I was wondering if it'd be efficient to mount all the different uploaders in a single polymorphic model so you don't have to create a different model every time you want to upload a different type of image/file. If you don't have much time you certainly don't need to bother answering this but any words on the matter are welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you have a typo at `ArticleThumb` model: you should have `:article_thumb` attribute to be `attr_accessible` but you have `:atricle_image` instead.

Another thing is that you dont wrap `<%= f.file_field :article_thumb %>` in a `simple_fields_for` block and `article_thumb` behaves like an Article's attribute.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. However, the problem still persists.

Comment: Well, then why you dont wrap `<%= f.file_field :article_thumb %>` in a `simple_fields_for` block? In your case `article_thumb` should be article's attribute, not article_thumb's.

Comment: This is the first thing I tried after waking up and it works perfectly now that I added `@article.article_thumbs.new` in Article#new. Thanks for your time.